# Exceptions and errors report order

Tags: java, scjp, open-closed-principle

What rules applies to the following code:

```
    try {
        assert (false) : "jane";
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        System.out.print("ae2 ");
    } finally {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Assetions are enabled.

Why IllegalArgumentException is reported instead of AssertionError? Are there any rules which applies in this situations?

**Edit:**
Sorry! in this example there should be assert (**false**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncaught exception in a `finally` block (or in a `catch` block) causes any exception from the `try` block to be discarded. See the [Java Language Specification § 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) for details. As of Java 7, an enclosing try/catch block can recover discarded exceptions (as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)).

Answer (score 6):

`finally` block always runs. The `assert` evaluates to true, so the `finally` block throws the exception.

Also, assertions are disabled by default anyway, which might be the reason why the assertion never got evaluated.

p.s

If the `assert` evaluates to false, `finally` will run anyway and throw the Exception, instead the `AssertionError`.

Remember `finally` block always runs, except when the JVM halts in the `try` block.

Comment: `assert` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok, to be precise i would say evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

The only line which does anything is

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

whereas

```
assert true
```

doesn't do anything and even if it did it wouldn't be caught by `catch(Exception`

Comment: In that case, the answer is that finally is always executed last and replaces any previous action except `System.exit();`

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block will always be executed. The only situation in which it **won't** be executed is a JVM shutdown (i.e. `System.exit(-)`.)

What you might find interesting is that even if you'd have:

```
try { 
    return ...; 
} 
finally { 
    ...
}
```

the finally block will still be executed, and it will be executed **before** the method exits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First time I've encountered somebody from PUT at Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Hah, nice to find university mate here ;-) Good luck with your SCJP.

Comment: Thanks, I've passed today exam with score 95% ;)